# Loop through a directory with any level of depth

Tags: linux, loops, command-line

I want to execute a command on all files present on all levels in the directory. It may have any number of files and sub directories. Even these sub directories may contain any number of files and subdirectories. I want to do this using shell script. As I am new to this field can any one suggest me a way out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive command that uses wildcard characters (*) like so:

```
for dir in ~/dev/myproject/*; do (cd "$dir" && git status); done
```

If you want to apply commands on the individual files you should use the find command and execute commands on it like so:

```
find yourdirectory -type f -exec echo "File found: '{}'" \;
```

What this does:

- finds all the items in the directory **yourdirectory**
- that have the **type f** - so are a file
- runs an **exec** on each file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command "find" with "xargs" after "|"(pipe).

Example: Suppose that I want to remove all files that have ".txt" extension on "Documents" directory:

```
find Documents -iname *.txt |xargs rm -f
```

Helps?

Comment: What if I want to pass the file name in the command I want to run on all files

Comment: I believe that I gave you the answer already! xargs will aplly any command you want. find with "-iname <FILE_NAME_OR_QUERY>" option will allows you to pass the file name. You must now put in a script to capture arguments. You can do with bash, receiving argument with '$1, $2,... $n' variables. Ex:

`startsearch=$1` and `filename=$2` and they apllying in the command above using $startsearch and $filename.

You can improve this by yourself!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use find:

> find -type f -exec COMMAND {} \;

-f applies the command only to files, not to directories. The command is recursive by default.

Comment: Note, that `find -exec` is really slow. `find | xargs` is way faster on large file sets. And it also can be paralleled.